# TypeORM migration timestamp type conversion

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

I currently have a column entity in my postgres database:

```
  @Column({
    type: 'timestamp without time zone',
    name: 'appointment_date_time',
    nullable: true,
  })
  appointmentDateTime: Date | null;
```

And I would like to convert all the existing `'appointment_date_time'` field into `'timestamp with time zone'` in a typeORM migration. For example, the existing `'appointment_date_time'` field was `2021-06-24 11:00:00` (timestamp without time zone) would be converted to `2021-06-24 11:00:00.000-00` (timestamp with time zone).

I tried this:

```
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner, TableColumn } from 'typeorm';

export class appointmentDateTimeWithTimeZone1625773516977 implements MigrationInterface {
  public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.changeColumn(
      'case',
      'appointment_date_time',
      new TableColumn({
        name: 'appointment_date_time',
        type: 'timestamp with time zone',
        isNullable: true,
      }),
    );
  }

  public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.changeColumn(
      'case',
      'appointment_date_time',
      new TableColumn({
        name: 'appointment_date_time',
        type: 'timestamp without time zone',
        isNullable: true,
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

But this overwrites all the existing 'appointment_date_time' data into null instead of converting them.